# Passing an int from MasterView to DetailView in a UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController in which i'm attempting to pass an int value from the MasterViewController to a DetailTableViewController. Both the master and the detail view controller are UITableViewControllers.  I am attempting to pass the indexPath.row value from the master to the detail which will dictate which array of objects is loaded into the detailViewController's tableview.

Some code from MasterViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int indexRowTouched = indexPath.row;

detailViewController = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@", detailViewController);

detailViewController.detailItem = indexRowTouched;
NSLog(@"index row %i", indexRowTouched);

}
```

An exception is thrown here

```
detailViewController.detailItem = indexRowTouched;
```

2012-03-28 16:08:19.625 splittest2[14895:f803] -[UINavigationController setDetailItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b592e0

From the DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(int)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
    }

if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
    [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }        
}
```

I also note that the value of detailItem logs "0" as soon as the detailView is loaded, before an indexPath row is selected at all.

Im wondering why this property is not being assigned from the MasterViewController, and the TableView is not being updated.

**EDIT**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int indexRowTouched = indexPath.row;

detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];

detailViewController.detailItem = indexRowTouched;
NSLog(@"index row %i", indexRowTouched);

}
```

Trying to access the setDetailItem on the UINavigationController seems to have been fixed by changing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `- (void)configureView` function, you are doing

```
if (self.detailItem) {
    if (detailItem == 0) {
        NSString *medPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"general" ofType:@"plist"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:medPath];

        self.items = dict;


        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

        [array addObjectsFromArray:[[self.items allKeys]
                                    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
        self.keys = array;

    }

    //etc
}
```

Since `detailItem` is an `int`, not an object, if it is equal to 0, `if (detailItem)` will return false. Thus if you are sending 0 to `detailItem`, your `configureView` if statement will not be entered and nothing will happen.

You should remove that outside if statement entirely and just have:

```
- (void)configureView {
    if (detailItem == 0) {
        NSString *medPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"general" ofType:@"plist"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:medPath];

        self.items = dict;


        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

        [array addObjectsFromArray:[[self.items allKeys]
                                    sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];
        self.keys = array;

    }

    //other cases for detailItem
}
```

Comment: thanks for having a look. I changed the way I was attempting to access the detailViewController (see above edit) and that seems to have helped, however the detailView object is still logging (null) on the detailViewController side.

Comment: It would really help to be able to see all of the code. Can you post a link to the whole .h and .m of DetailViewController (an image would be ok too).

Comment: http://db.tt/oxYkgm5o, http://db.tt/IBJJ9f9J, http://db.tt/zKgqdogd, http://db.tt/2zAyngXa, MasterViewController.h/m and DetailViewController.h/m

Comment: Yep... thats exactly it. I had a feeling it had something to do with that... thank you for taking the time to help! I removed the first if statement and then added `[self.tableview reloadData]` to each case and it performs perfectly. Thanks again!